# Migrating from MySQL to Couchbase Server (NoSQL)

Tags: mysql, json, couchbase, nosql

I am planning to move some of my RDBMS tables to a NoSQL environment. I have different modules and associated tables as shown below.

```
1. General 
    News table
    Trainings table 
    Knowledge table
 2. Application_x
    Clicks table
    Crashes table
```

Note : This is a sample scenario

In this case, this is how i defined Nosql (`Couchbase server`) structure. Please correct me if this is wrong.

The purpose of migration is mainly intended for searching.

```
{
    "General":[
        "news" : [{
            "id" : "123",
            "title" : "test title"
        },
        {
            "id" : "345",
            "title" : "test title 2"
        }],
        "trainings" :[{
            "id" : "1",
            "name" : "training 1"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "name" : "training 2"
        }],
        "knowledge" :[{
            "id" : "1",
            "categ" : "programming"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "categ" : "management"
        }]
    ],
    "Application_x": [
        "clicks" : [{
            "userid" : "1",
            "area" : "1850",
        },
        {
            "userid" : "2",
            "area" : "258",
        }],
        "crashes" :[{
            "userid" : "1",
            "severity" : "1",
        },
        {
            "userid" : "2",
            "severity" : "8",
        }]
    ]
}
```

Can someone correct me if my approach is not correct ?

Thanks in advance,
Tismon Varghese.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your question, I am left scratching my head as to what your approach is.  In a NoSQL database (such as couchbase) - you don't have the idea of tables and columns. Each object is serialized to JSON and stored in plain text. Yes, this creates duplication, but the drawbacks of duplication are greatly outweighed by the benefits of scalability.

In this example, using Couchbase, you would probably want to create one Couchbase bucket per application. That way, should you need to migrate to a different Couchbase cluster at a later date, a minimal amount of configuration is required.  Each row in your tables gets created as a separate object in Couchbase. There is no need to separate the object types within the bucket.

[This blog entry](http://blog.couchbase.com/sql-nosql-copy-your-data-mysql-couchbase) contains some detailed instructions on how to migrate from mySQL to Couchbase.

On a side note, I might recommend using Couchbase combined with [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/).